# How to mock a MyBatis mapper method using JMockit

Tags: jmockit

We have a service component (@service) which internally uses MyBatis to do CRUD operations. All the components are managed by Spring.

Lets assume our MyBatis mapper file

```
class MyBatisMapper{

        public void getData(Map<String,Object> arg);
}
```

In our mybatis xml file,we have  element defined for a callable statement. arg is a map which holds IN and OUT parameters.

Our service component is like

```
@Service("myService")
class MyService{

@Autowired
private MyBatisMapper myMapper;

public void processData(){

  Map<String,Object> input = new HashMap<String,Object>();
  ............
  ............
  myMapper.getDat(input);

  Object response =  input.get("RESPONSE");
  //process response and so on
}
```

My objective is to write Junits for the service component and don't have to interact with DB. So, I tried to use JMockIt to mock some of the DAO operations

My attempt is ike

```
@Mocked
@Injectable
private MyBatisMapper myMapper;

@Test
    public void testService() {

        new NonStrictExpectations(){
            {
                Map<String,Object> input = new HashMap<String,Object>();
                                 input.put("xxx,"yyy");
                myMapper.getData(input);
            }
        };

    }
```

But when I ran my tests, I noticed that call went through actualy DB , instead of mocked one.

How to make sure only the mocked components gets called, instead of the actual object

Answer (score 0):

`@Injectable` mock instances only get injected into `@Tested` objects. And to specify a return value from a mocked method, you need to assign it to the `result` field. So, the test should look like the following:

```
@Tested MyService myService;
@Injectable MyBatisMapper myMapper;

@Test
public void testService() {
    final Map<String,Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    data.put("RESPONSE", "yyy");

    new Expectations() {{
        myMapper.getData((Map<String, Object>) any); result = data;
    }};

    myService.processData();

    // Assert some expected outcome.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Rogerio. I tried to follow the approach you mentioned, but still I see the call going to the actual object. There is a point which I did not mention earlier. My project is spring based and the components are all autowired.

My test has

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:spring/test-applicationContext.xml"})
```

and test-applicationContext.xml has component scan. So I think, Spring is injecting the actual object ignoring the mock instruction.

Am I wrong ?